# Laravel with Mysql calculate percentage of "like" query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4, sql-like

I have a search bar on my header which displays the results of a query string, for example "car". I have to do a query on 2 tables and then do a union all to combine both results to then display them.

What i don't want is for all the results for the first query to all appear on top and the rest of the second results to go on bottom. So i had an idea to calculate the percentage of the match of the "like" then re-arrange the results so it looks diverse. I honestly have no clue how to do this.

Example:

query string = car

first table being queried:

```
id | name | 
1   red carts
2   carrots
3   purple
```

second table being queried:

```
id | name | 
1   cars
2   cat
3   red
```

The following would be my results as of how i have my logic right now (which is query first table then combine with second table results).
just guessing the order of the first table btw.

```
carrots   (first table)
red carts (first table)
cars      (second table)
```

What i would like it to do is for mysql to return me a % of how much the "like" clause equalled. So if the following was correct:

```
carrots   (30%)
red carts (80%)
cars      (50%)
```

What i would then do is just do an array map and order by the percentage.
(Hopefully i can get mysql to return the % as a column) Which will bring the final results:

```
red carts (80%, table 1) 
cars      (50%, tables 2)
carrots   (30%, table 3)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT
thanks for any feedback, after searching a little more, i have learned about fulltext search on mysql. Pretty much it does exactly what i wanted.

For anyone trying to implement the same thing, i suggest the following links.

[MySQL Full-Text Search with Multiple words](http://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/)

[mySQL Full Text Search With Percentage Scoring](http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/php/mysql-full-text-search-with-percentage-scoring/)

Comment: Can you please clarify: "return me a % of how much the "like" clause equalled"

Comment: i dont know if this helps but i guess the term would be "pattern matching" @mkaatman

Comment: Give us an example query and the expected numbers from it.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer.